# How do you cause a Registry Key to overwrite an existing key with Visual Studio Installer

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer, registry

I am using the Visual Studio Installer Project to create an msi for an application I have built that I want to make the default application for a certain protocol.

While the key gets created if it is not already set up on the computer if it exists it is not overwritten. Is there an obvious setting I am missing?

The key is going in

```
HKCR\[protocol]\shell\open\command
```

Then it is the `(Default)` key.

Answer (score 0):

Check out your [REINSTALLMODE property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371182%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) which should be defaulted to "omus". You would be interested in "m" (Rewrite all required registry entries from the Registry Table that go to the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` or `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`) and may be in "u" (Rewrite all required registry entries from the Registry Table that go to the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` or `HKEY_USERS`). This property should normally always be used in conjunction with the [REINSTALL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371175(v=vs.85).aspx) property. However, this property can also be used during installation, not just reinstall.

If you use command line to run your MSI (via msiexec.exe) you would need to look at Windows Installer [Command-Line Options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367988(v=vs.85).aspx). Once again you would need to look at `"/f"` switch with "u" and "m" options